# Discuss the convergence of the improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(ln x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Discuss the convergence of the improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x(\ln x)^2}dx$

Comment: Why don't you start the discussion...

Comment: Sir I will do from now on wards sir

Answer (score 5):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_2^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x\log^2(x)}\,dx\right|&\le \int_2^\infty \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x\log^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\le \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\log(2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This s a improper integral , so which test you are applying sir

Comment: It is improper as a Riemann integral.  It is a well-defined Lebesgue integral.  In either case, this test is the comparison test.

Comment: sir which means we have take $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x\log^2(x)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)},$ then I can use the limit comparision test sir..I am right sir

Comment: Yes.  Well done!  You have it!

Answer (score 1):

The integral is convergent by (the integral version of) [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test): $\sin(x)$ is a function with a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}$ is a positive function on $(2,+\infty)$, decreasing to zero.

Additionally,
$$ \int_{e}^{e^M}\frac{\sin x}{x\log^2 x}\,dx = \int_{1}^{M}\frac{\sin(e^u)}{u^2}\,du \leq \int_{1}^{M}\frac{du}{u^2} = 1-\frac{1}{M}. $$